# $\mathsf{ZF}$ defines a transitive class $M \models \mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathsf{CH}$ implies inconsistent (Kunen's Set Theory, Remark II.6.32)

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, incompleteness

This is Remark II.6.32 from Kunen's Set Theory, which puzzles me:

> Suppose that working in $\mathsf{ZF}$ (or even $\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L$), one could define a transitive proper class $M$ and prove that it is a model for $\mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathsf{CH}$ (or even just $\mathsf{ZF} + V \neq L$). Then $\mathsf{ZF}$ is inconsistent.

I understand the proof they provided, which uses the absoluteness of rank and $L(\delta)$. What I'm confused about is that the statement itself appears to very simply contradict Godel's second incompleteness theorem - if $M \models \mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathsf{CH}$, then certainly $M \models \mathsf{ZF}$, so $\mathsf{ZF} \vdash \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZF})$, a contradiction.

Is there a mistake in my reasoning? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of a proper class which we can prove each relativized ZF axiom does not prove the consistency of ZF. To see the absurdity of this, observe that $V$ is a proper class for which we can prove each relativized axiom... since each relativized axiom is just an axiom we take. So if that sufficed to prove consistency of ZF, we would be in violation of Godel's theorem from the get-go.

In order to prove the consistency of ZF within ZF, we would need to find a model that we could *internally* prove that every axiom holds. In other words we can prove the *internally quantified* statement "for every axiom $\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$ of ZF, $M\models \ulcorner\phi\urcorner$." (I use "Quine corners" to emphasize this is an internal code for the formula as a set.) This is different from the sense in this theorem, which is to say for every axiom $\phi$ of ZF we can prove "$\phi^M$."

Comment: I think I understand, but let me clarify just to be 100% sure. What the remark is stating is that, working in $\mathsf{ZF}$, we can produce a model $M$ such that $M$ proves all axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$ relativised to $M$. To contradict the incompleteness theorem, we require $M$ to prove all (non-relativised) axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$. Am I correct?

Comment: In particular, we can't have that $M \preccurlyeq V$.

Comment: @ClementYung $M$ is a structure so it doesn't prove things, but that's just a minor issue where you should replace "proves" with "satisfies". But I think you're still missing the main point, which is where we're saying "for all"... in one case it's in the metatheory and in the other case it's in the theory. (cont)

Comment: @ClementYung We might informally say "$V$ is a proper class model of ZF", which is the statement in the metatheory "for all axioms $\phi$ of ZF, $ZF\vdash V\models \phi$." This is true, but doesn't imply ZF proves Con(ZF). What would prove that would be if we had ZF $\vdash$"for all axioms $\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$ of ZF, $V\models\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$". But we don't have that... in fact we can't even express it because by Tarski's theorem we can't express "$V\models \ulcorner\phi\urcorner$."

Comment: @ClementYung What we would usually have when we can prove consistency (e.g ZF can prove consistency of Zermelo set theory Z) is a *set* model, where we can express the satisfaction relation. For instance $ZF\vdash$ "for every axiom $\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$ of Z, $V_{\omega\cdot 2}\models \ulcorner\phi\urcorner$." So ZF proves Con(Z).

Comment: I see, I think you're emphasising on that the statement "for every axiom $\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$, <something> $\models \ulcorner\phi\urcorner$" has to be able to be *internally quantified*, followed by that (in this context) $\mathsf{ZF}$ can prove this statement. But in the case of $V$, replacing <something> with $V$ proves to be a statement that cannot be internally quantified.